# How do I include dependencies for embedded console apps when using Run From Package

Tags: python, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions, blender

I'm deploying my Azure Function app using a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps. The function invokes three console applications that are included in the package. One of the console applications is a stand alone .exe, it works without issue. The other two have dependencies to a number of dll:s that are also included in the package. This setup works well on my local machine, and when deployed using WebDeploy.

When instead deploying using Run From Package to a freshly created Function App Service, the function app itself loads fine as well as the standalone .exe console app, but both console apps that have dll dependencies fail to run, and both return with exit code 0xC0000135 to my function app (indicating that a dll failed to load).

Now, if I deploy once using Webdeploy and then deploy again using Run From Package, I get the latest build installed - and the console apps now work (!). I think this might be due to the .exe not being able to access the virtual file system when loading the dll:s, is this correct?

I could stick with WebDeploy but I really want to use the package deploy since the cold start time is much faster during scale-out (will need 100+ instances in production). I am also concerned that this way, the app actually needs to copy *both* the zip package, *and* the site structure under wwwroot, causing additional overhead.

What is the best way to include dependencies such as dll:s in a package when using Run From Package with Azure Functions?

(The function app is v3, built using .NET Core 3.1)

Comment: If the DLLs required by the console app DLL are in the same folder, I believe they should get picked up by default without issue. Could you confirm if that is true for your package?

Comment: Thanks for responding @PramodValavala-MSFT, I can confirm that one of the console apps has its DLL:s in the same folder. The other app has a total of 17 DLL:s in two separate folders.